# add space in string when meeting a given pattern

Tags: r

I have a string as follows:

```
a<-c("AbcDef(123)")
> a
[1] "AbcDef(123)"
```

Is there any efficient way to transform it as

`a<-c("Abc Def (123)")`

In other words, I would like to add a space when meeting a upper case or a special character ( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possibility :

```
 gsub("(?<=[^A-Z(])(?=[A-Z(])", " ", a, perl=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gsub("(?<=.)([A-Z(])", " \\1", a, perl = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
[1] "Abc Def (123)"
```

If the string with spaces has no one-character pieces it can be simplified to this:

```
gsub("(.)([A-Z(])", "\\1 \\2", a)
```

Comment: This won't work on a string like "AbcDef(123)AaA(fsfsd)AAA". @droopy's solution will work on any string

Answer (score 0):

Mine's a bit kludgy and uses two `gsub`s. The inner `gsub` adds spaces, the outer `gsub` removes the leading whitespace.

```
a <- "AbcDef(123)"
gsub("^\\s", "", gsub("([A-Z(])", " \\1", a))
```